# android pass array of widgets to another class and iterate over them to change properties

Tags: android, class, android-widget, compare, extends

still too new to android, minset from Object-C where this is trivial.

I have a Class A with a couple of widgets

Also a => Class B extends TextView

Class A uses instance of Class B.

When text is entered in class B i want to iterate over an array of widgets from A, of different types (spinner, textview, etc) but that have common property, setVisibility, and change it

so in class A, after creating the field member Class B, I pass an Object array with two widgets on it to it (to Class B)

So, naively, i've tried several variations of a for loop with casting, such as (only not giving error thus far, but there is a problem:

```
        for (Object o : hidObj) 
        {

            Class c=o.getClass(); //.setVisibility=1;
            if (c.getSuperclass()==android.view.View.class){};
        }
```

Problem: hidObj array contains on TextView and one Spinner in this case (I want this to work for other activities)

but
TextView:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
```

while Spinner:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.view.ViewGroup
           ↳    android.widget.AdapterView<T extends android.widget.Adapter>
               ↳    android.widget.AbsSpinner
                   ↳    android.widget.Spinner
```

so right off that wont work.

any suggestion from the Android/Java gurus?

Many thanks in advance

David

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the common `setVisibility()` method that you want to call is common because it is inherited by the widgets from `View`. You are expected to leverage standard Java language and inheritance, thus:

```
View view;
view = findViewById(R.id.somename); // Can be any kind of View (TextView, Spinner, etc).
view.setVisibility(true); // or false depending on your needs.
```

Now, if you want to check any particular Object whose hierarchy you don't know, then you have to use reflection. See [Using Java Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/); you'll be interested in the section "Invoking methods by name".

Answer (score 0):

- setVisibility is a method from class View.
- TextView extends View
- Spinner extends View

-> pass an array of View, and each item of the array has the method setVisibility

you don't need to cast

Comment: hi guys, haven forgotten to answer this one, I'm just busy putting an update for an iOS app of mine out there. Will try it this week and marked as answered if i get to have it work out.